# Is there a way to check voted comments?

Tags: support, comments, badges

I wonder if there is a way to check more or less quickly if your comments where voted. I specifically had the problem that I wanted to check how far away I was from the "pundit" medal, that requires 10 comments with score of 5 or more. The only way to check that I found is to go through the comments one by one, but this is not practical if you have hundreds of comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here you go](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/238582/comments-and-votes).

Enter your user ID and run the query, it will list all your comments, beginning with the highest voted, so you can easily count how many you have over 5 votes.

Comment: I tried but failed. Could you please write the exact query? Thanks!

Comment: @Wolphramjonny: looking at the linked query, it looks like it's for StackOverflow. You need to enter `Physics` into the box next to `Switch site` at the bottom for it to be here.

Comment: @KyleKanos thanks, I got it!

Comment: @KyleKanos, what is ID? the username?

Comment: @GreenRay: When you check your user profile, the search bar at the top of the page reads something like `user:########`, the number there is your UserID.